# What is this crow eating, and is it a common part of the corvid diet?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, ornithology, behaviour

Here's [a picture](http://theearlybirder.com/corvids/am-crow/pages/6002831%20American%20Crow.htm) (by Rob Curtis) of a crow carrying and eating the corpse of what looks a bit like a small hawk or falcon:

[image: Crow carrying dead bird]

[Other](http://theearlybirder.com/corvids/am-crow/pages/6003000%20American%20Crow.htm) [pictures](http://theearlybirder.com/corvids/am-crow/pages/6002847%20American%20Crow.htm) clearly show the crow is eating the dead bird. [This image](http://theearlybirder.com/corvids/am-crow/pages/6002847%20American%20Crow.htm) shows the underside of the head and beak; [this one](http://theearlybirder.com/corvids/am-crow/pages/6002825%20American%20Crow.htm) shows its legs, which are grayish.

1. **What bird is being eaten?**
2. **Is this bird a usual part of the corvid diet?** Or did the crow just opportunistically scavenge a dead bird?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Crows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow#Diet) are omnivorous, and will eat almost anything they find or can kill.

In this case the prey looks like a [Yellow-Shafted Flicker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_flicker).

[image]

Comment: I would add that most corvid are scavengers, and there are also some that are "specialized" at that, such as the [Carrion Crow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrion_Crow) (*Corvus corone*).

Comment: Also, do you think the crow killed the woodpecker (rather than scavenging it)?

Comment: @Mechanical snail - I don't think that there is any way that anyone could know the answer to this question unless they were a witness to what happened.

Comment: I agree with @AlanBoyd that we cannot know for sure but I would say it is unlikely that a crow could catch and kill a healthy flicker.  So just based on that, it seems more likely it scavenged it.

Comment: The crow looks like it is just admiring the dead flickers' colors. I think it picked it up in the way it would pick up any colorful thing. The flicker probable died by flying into a window.

Answer (score 1):

It's eating a flicker woodpecker. And yes, it did kill it and is eating it. Crows and ravens are omnivorous but also predators. They will opportunistically kill any small prey they can catch. Most birds are too quick for a crow, but flickers and all woodpeckers are notoriously slow flyers. It's about the only type of bird that is both small enough and slow enough for a crow to catch. Attached are some images of crows as predators.

[image: Crow v Flicker 1]

[image: Crow v Flicker 2]

[image: Crow v Flicker 3]

[image: Crow v Rabbit 1]

[image: Crow v Rabbit 2]

[image: Crow v Rabbit 3]

[image: Crow v Rabbit 4]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This looks like a good answer, but answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, it is hard to know whether this is normal behavior. This is a good example of how to [format references](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59698/46609). ——— You may also want to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you!

Comment: In addition, please provide a citation/source for the images you are using — images must be credited to their creators just like [quotes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) are to their authors. This is generally considered good practice in scientific communication and will help other users understand by providing context.